# CSS background image scroll animation

Tags: html, css

I have managed to have an imaged scrolled in the bg, but the problem is that for the pages which it's height is more than screen size height, the animation is not shown in the bottom of the page (the overflowed part)

here is the fiddle:
[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tdfznx5t/)

the CSS for the background animation:

```
#main-banner .bg-animation{
    background: url('http://pentathemes.com/saasapp/images/intro-bg.gif') 0 0 repeat;
    -webkit-animation: animate_background 10s linear 0s infinite;
    -moz-animation: animate_background 10s linear 0s infinite;
    -o-animation: animate_background 10s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: animate_background 10s linear 0s infinite;
    height:100vh;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate_background { 
    from { 
        background-position: 0 0;
    } 
    to { 
        background-position: 0 -200px;
    } 
}
@-moz-keyframes animate_background { 
    from { 
        background-position: 0 0;
    } 
    to { 
        background-position: 0 -200px;
    } 
}
@-o-keyframes animate_background { 
    from { 
        background-position: 0 0;
    } 
    to { 
        background-position: 0 -200px;
    } 
}
@keyframes animate_background { 
    from { 
        background-position: 0 0;
    } 
    to { 
        background-position: 0 -200px;
    } 
}
```

As you can see in the above example, the animation is not applied to the bottom of the page for the last lines.

How this could be fixed? Thanks

Comment: works for me on Chrome 52

Comment: @e-neko scroll down in the demo, you will see the bottom has no background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i see the problem now.

Replace `height:100vh;` with `min-height: 100vh; height:100%;`

Comment: another thing, after about 7 seconds the background image flashes and it seems it starts from the beginning again, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @behz4d yes, notice that the original image height is 480 pixels. Your code animates only from 0 to -200. If you make it to -480, it will be seamless. The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e_neko/tdfznx5t/2/  . You may consider making the animation longer to preserve the speed, 24 seconds should do the trick.

Comment: Btw, sorry for off-topic, but it's a very nice background :-)